# Trouble with SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, centos-6, sshd

I am having trouble using `ssh`.  I seem to be able to ssh out of the machine, but I can not locally ssh to the machine, nor can i ssh from a remote machine.
I have checked the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and when I start the service it states that it is OK, but when checking the status I get "openssh-daemon is stopped".  What am I doing wrong?

I working with Centos 6.3 and about to lose whatever hair I have

---

`netstat -int | grep 22` gives no response and shows that most of the `xinetd` services are off

---

Dirk `ssh -v -v -v` returns nothing, and I am get no log information. the problem is the openssh which does not start even when it is started.

Comment: Can you see a listen port? `netstat -lnt | grep 22` What does `chkconfig --list sshd` say?

Comment: How do you start the service? How do you get the status? Do you have a firewall activated? Is the ssh port you are using in the firewall rules? Which is your sshd port (you can get it with `grep -i ^port /etc/ssh/sshd_config`).

Comment: @ray, if you don't have anything listening, it obviously won't let you log in. Try `service sshd start` and then see if it's listening.

Comment: We're working on getting your accounts merged. Once that's done, you can add comments to answers below.

Answer (score 0):

To debug your problem you may inspect the output of `ssh -v -v -v ...`.

Also you may increase the `sshd` logging level in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
  LogLevel DEBUG
```

The logging output goes normally to `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: `ssh -vvv` also does the job ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Dirk `ssh -v -v -v` returns nothing, and I am get no log information.
>   the problem is the openssh which does not start even when it is
>   started.

Indicates that the problem is the daemon which doesn't start.

Run this (`sudo chkconfig --list sshd`), and show us the output. On my machine it looks as follows:

```
$ chkconfig --list sshd
sshd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

also run `service sshd restart` and show the output - should look like this, first line is likely "Failed" or so in your case:

```
$ sudo service sshd restart
Stopping sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
```

To start it upon boot do:

```
sudo chkconfig sshd on
```

and list again what it looks like with

```
chkconfig --list sshd
```

After that step continue debugging with the steps outlined below the horizontal rule if you're still having trouble.

---

First verify `sshd` is indeed running on its default port:

```
sudo lsof -i :22
```

(you can also use one of the `netstat` lines suggested in comments).

Assuming Linux - you gave no indication which OS you are using - try something along the lines of `/etc/init/sshd restart`. The name of the service could of course differ, e.g. be `openssh`, `ssh` or so ...

What I have been doing in the past to diagnose `ssh` problems both on the server-side and the client-side is something similar to what Dirk suggests in his answer ... but extended.

You want to use the same machine, fine. So run in one tab/window the command (for the "server"):

```
sudo $(which sshd) -dDp 22222
```

on the client side run:

```
ssh -vvvvp 22222 localhost
```

Does the first tab/window show anything? If it doesn't we already have an indication. It's likely some weird firewall rule or you gave some strange setting for the `Listen` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. If that's the case please paste it and we'll go from there.

Comment: The reason for the somewhat convoluted `sudo $(which sshd) -dDp 22222` is that `sshd` wants to be run with its absolute path and refuses to run otherwise. At least on some of my systems. Of course you could also separate these steps.